# how to get one form value inside another form action in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

Am using spring mvc i have two forms in a single jsp version am using is spring 3.1.2

```
<form:form method="get" commandName="command1" action="form1.htm">
</form:form>   

<form:form method="get" commandName="command2" action="form2.htm">
    <form:submit value='Save'>
    </form:form>

@RequestMapping(value = "/form1", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "Get")
            public String method1(
                    @ModelAttribute("command1") Object1 object1 {
    
      
        }

@RequestMapping(value = "/form2", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "Get")
    public String method2(
            @ModelAttribute("command2") Object2 object2 {
    // Here i want to access object1 how to do this 

}
```

**Things i tried.**

Kept one hidden field in form2 holding form1 object and i can access that.
Or setting that form1 value in session and i can access that

But i want to know the best way to do this in spring mvc

Comment: Try to use Form1 within Form2. So when you submit Form2, you will get Form1 object in Form2.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.No as per my design i have to keep both as separate form only

Comment: What do you mean exactly, since the 2 forms are completely separate from each other, either form1 or form2 will be submitted and there is no spring way to do this. You need to hack some way to do it, like you have done already. I would suggest you to reconsider your design.

Comment: Mr varun In my form i have two actions one in post and another in get so only i separated into two form Is there any way to do this in single form Please help me I will change my design

Answer (score 2):

You can combine this two form together something like this

***Your JSP***

```
<form:form method="get" commandName="command1" action="form1.htm">
    <!-- field of form 1 -->
    <form:input path="frm1Field1" />
    <form:form method="get" commandName="command2" action="form2.htm">
        <!-- field of form 2 -->    
        <form:input path="frm2Field1" />
        <form:input path="frm2Field2" />
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form:form>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form:form>
```

***Criteria Clasess***

```
public class Form2 {
private String frm2Field1;
private String frm2Field2;
//setter & getter methods
}


public class Form1 extends Form2 {
private String  frm1Field1;
//setter & getter methods
}
```

***Controllers***

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form1", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "Get")
public String method1(@ModelAttribute("command1")Form1 form1){
form1.getFrm1Field1();
//access value of for2 
form1.getFrm2Field1();
form1.getFrm2Field2();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/form2", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "Get")
public String method2(@ModelAttribute("command2")Form2 form2) {
form2.getFrm2Field1();
form2.getFrm2Field2();
}
```

hope this will solve your problem